Identifying a movie from a vague audio description of children repeating "we believe"
Not being able to remember this is absolutely driving me crazy, but I have so little info to search with.
The one sound clip in my head is children (higher pitched voices) meekly saying "we believe" over and over again.  I really do not remember the video/image that goes along with the sound.
I'm sure it was made between 1985 and 2005 but most likely in the late 1990's.  It was probably a Hollywood movie, but it at least definitely had a United States origin.  Probably live action.  Probably marketed for middle class white American adults with or without families. If I had to guess, I'm sure the cast was mostly white.  I could be wrong.  I generally prefer watching 'weird' or disturbing movies, but I'm pretty sure this isn't in that category.  No clue what they need to believe in.
I caught myself mocking it a few days ago but I have no idea where it's from.

This is not a lot to go on, I'm afraid, but I appreciate you trying to add as many background details as possible. See this clip from Gregg Araki's Nowhere from 1997; it might be what you're after.

That's amazing.... That's absolutely it. I thought it was from Patch Adams or an obscure version of Peter Pan.   I was obsessed with Nowhere (and the Doom Generation) at the being of high school.

No problem. While not exactly obsessed with him, I'm familiar with his work and fond of... some of it. ;)

@Walt You should add your comment as an answer.

@matt_black OK, done.

I'm afraid it was one of those 'weirder' movies. ;) You're looking for Gregg Araki's Nowhere from 1997 starring  Heather Graham, Ryan Phillippe, Mena Suvari and Denise Richards before they made it big, as well as Shannen Doherty, Debi Mazar, Christina Applegate and many others.

A group of teenagers try to sort out their lives and emotions while bizarre experiences happen to each one, including alien abductions, bad acid trips, bisexual experiences, suicides, bizarre deaths, and a rape by a TV star. All of this happens before "the greatest party of the year".

John Ritter plays a TV evangelist and at some point his audience, and 2 of the film's young characters, repeat the phrase 'we believe' over and over in a meek voice. Here's the trailer:



